# Entity Framework Code templates and foreign keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

How do i get Entity Frameworks foreign keys to pick up when I generate the view with the add view dialog.

My Models are like

```
public class System
{
    #region Properties

    public int SystemId { get; set; }
    public string SystemName { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public class Module
{
    #region Properties

    public int ModuleId { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    [Display(Name="Module Name")]
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Date Added")]
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("CurrentSystem")]

    public int SystemId { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey()]
    //[ForeignKey("SystemId")]
    public System System { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

When i click on the Controller, then Add View, the modal opens. I select all the details that is needed and then the following is generated ( I did not include the entire view).

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Module</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModuleName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ModuleName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModuleName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateAdded)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateAdded)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateAdded)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SystemId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SystemId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SystemId)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

I want the SystemId to be a dropdown and not a text field. How do i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you created a class derived from dbContext with a property of type `DBSet<System>` and a property of type `DBSet<module>` ?
Provided you have, and you select a controller with the option "read and write actions with entity framework" and select both your class Module) and your context in the drop downs below that, MVC should generate the correct code view and controller code to display a combo for the system.

It worked for me in MVC4, at least. Remember to generate your project before trying to add a controller. I think MVc uses reflection so it needs an up-to-date assembly...

Answer (score 1):

Use a view-model. MVC uses the data annotations to figure out how to display the properties. If you want your view to behave in a different manner than your model, you need to map your model to a view-model to handle the extra logic (ie a drop down where an int exists).  Then generate your view from the view-model class.

The view-model adds a layer to deal with the seperations of concerns here. You want your view to be different than your model will allow so add a view model class that will take the model data and display it in a way that you want.